# Sending AND Receiving Payments with Paypal on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, e-commerce, activemerchant

I am building a marketplace app for a client and need to be able to both send payments and receive payments.  I am currently using ActiveMerchant to handle incoming payments, but I don't see anywhere in the documentation if it is possible to SEND payments.  I've read elsewhere that it may in fact be possible to send payments using one of Paypal's many API's but I'm not sure which one I should be looking to use.

If anyone has ever had to SEND payments within a rails system I would appreciate some insight, where to start looking, gems, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/adaptive_payments) it seems to offer something similar to what you are looking for. There is also a gem for it [over here](http://rubygems.org/gems/paypal_adaptive) which seems to be actively developed.

If this wont work for you for any reason let me know and I can look for something else.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal supports it with MassPay. Not sure about ActiveMerchant.
(To get MassPay enabled on the live PayPal site, contact CS. For Sandbox, log a ticket at https://www.paypal.com/mts/).